# "related to educational contexts" vs. "related to education"

Tags: word-usage

[From a tutorial](http://edc.edu.hk/courses/ielts14test1/lessons/ielts-14-test-1-listening/)

> This test consists of four sections, each with ten questions. The first two sections are concerned with social needs. The first section is a conversation between two speakers and the second section is a monologue. The final two sections are concerned with situations **related to educational or training contexts**. The third section is a conversation between up to four people and the fourth section is a monologue.

Does the following wording mean the same thing as above?

> ... The final two sections are concerned with situations **related to education or training** ...

In other words, do "related to educational contexts" and "related to education" mean the same thing?

According to [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=related%20to%20education%2C%20related%20to%20educational%20contexts&corpus=15&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&direct_url=t4%3B%2Crelated%20to%20education%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brelated%20to%20education%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRelated%20to%20Education%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRELATED%20TO%20EDUCATION%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brelated%20to%20Education%3B%2Cc0), no one says the former

[image]

Comment: To my eye, without seeing what the actual paper says, they _could_ be interchangeable, but it could be emphasising the fact it's concerning things around education (such as, say, classroom structure) rather than the education itself (such as the material being covered)...

Comment: @kaipmdh Thank you. Does "it could be emphasising the fact" refer to the former or the latter?

Comment: By "former" do you mean the text as given with "contexts"? If yes, then yes, that's what I meant.